# pandas merge interactions that are less than 20 seconds from each other

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge my interactions dataset if they took place 0-20 seconds from each other.

First lines of my CSV file:

```
Source,     Target,     time_start, time_end,  total_time
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1532,       1583,      51
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1627,       1652,      25
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1755,       2492,      737
0x597E5627, 0x3C3A21AD, 2649,       2681,      32
0x597E5627, 0x3C3A21AD, 3028,       3058,      30
0x597E5627, 0x3C3A21AD, 3071,       3094,      23
```

What the output should be (notice the last line):

```
Source,     Target,     time_start,  time_end,  total_time
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1532,        1583,    51
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1627,        1652,    25
0x597E5627, 0x3C992634, 1755,        2492,    737
0x597E5627, 0x3C3A21AD, 2649,        2681,    32
0x597E5627, 0x3C3A21AD, 3028,        3094,    53
```

Because the last interactions was time_start 3071- time_end 3058 = 13 seconds from each other so I consider that to still be 1 conversation.

Right now the code seems to work.  I succeeded in finding the cases that need to be merged and I made a cumulative list of which groups of interactions occur in my data, but my output only shows the seconds and filtered out the names of my chips.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filter20seconds.csv')

start_end_differences = df.time_start  - df.time_end.shift(1)
threshold_selector = start_end_differences > 20 
groups = threshold_selector.cumsum()
new = df.groupby(groups).agg({'time_start':min, 'time_end':max, 
      'total_time':sum})

print(new)
```

Does anybody spot what I did wrong that the names of source and target disappeared?

My output now:

```
     time_start  time_end  total_time
0          1532      1583          51
1          1627      1652          25
2          1755      2492         737
3          2649      2681          32
4          3028      3094          53
```

------------- a problem occurred ----

```
Source,     Target,     time_start, time_end, total_time
0x6979EF0C, 0x300C163D, 6049,       6083,     34
0x6979EF0C, 0x300C163D, 6125,       6236,     111
0x15697F98, 0x3C3A21AD, 1855,       1875,     20
0x15697F98, 0x064F5882, 2749,       2776,     27
0x15697F98, 0x064F5882, 3040,       3078,     38
```

here, the rows with the calculation 1855-6236 will be merged since that is lower than 20.

Comment: So what would you do with 20 events, each separated 5 seconds from the previous one?

Comment: if the events are with the same chips then i believe they should be merged to be able to know how long each interaction truly took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you build a graph with the indices as nodes

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.index)
```

Add ass edges all row-pairs with distance less than 20:

```
G.add_edges_from(
    [(r1[0], r2[0]) for (r1, r2) in itertools.product(df.iterrows(), df.iterrows()) if r1[0] < r2[0] and r1[1]['time_end'] + 20 > r2[1]['time_start']]
)
```

Now find all the connected-components:

```
groups = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(ee, i) for ee in e] for (i, e) in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))]))
>>> df.index.map(lambda j: groups[j])
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Note that 4 and 5 have been identified correctly as belonging to the same group.

At this point, you just need to group by `groups` in the usual way. For example, for the start time:

```
>>> df.time_start.groupby(df.index.map(lambda j: groups[j])).min()
0    1532
1    1627
2    1755
3    2649
4    3028
Name: time_start, dtype: int64
```